# How to avoid LOGENTRIES_TOKEN spam logs in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, debugging, logging

When i run the `python manage.py <somecmd>`, i'm getting the below error:

```bash
It appears the LOGENTRIES_TOKEN parameter you entered is incorrect!
```

How can i disable this log, this log spamming across the access log.

I've tried to control it using log_level as of now, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `verbose` to False in the config will stop the 'incorrect log_entries token' log, we need to set it everywhere we're using the `logentries.LogentriesHandler`

Prev version:

```json
"logentries": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "token": os.environ.get("LE_TOKEN", ""),
            "class": "logentries.LogentriesHandler",
            ...
            ...
        }
```

Current version:

```json
"logentries": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "verbose": False,
            "token": os.environ.get("LE_TOKEN", ""),
            "class": "logentries.LogentriesHandler",
            ...
            ...
        }
```